# How do I remove the RSS Feed Redirect?

Tags: redirect, rss

Currently all the feed URL's for our site forward to /feed/

For example:

www.wgel.net/feed/rss2/ forwards to www.wgel.net/feed/

The problem is that /feed/ is ATOM format and I need to get the RSS2 format because we are trying to pull from our feed into Contstant Contact. CC says they need an RSS2 formatted feed, when I give them our current feed address the system errors out and says it's invalid.

So something is causing a forward from /rss2/ that I think I need to turn off?

Checked the httaccess file and there is nothing in there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Same behavior with the default theme and without plugins? Try also to re-save permalinks.

Comment: The URL /feed/ in your question get a RSS2 format on default, WP default. I try them also to before view seconds. Maybe you have an aggregator active their search for the Atom format and use the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Default feed *is* RSS2, see [`get_default_feed()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_default_feed/). If you are getting different behavior then something in your install is interfering with it.